# tableView not found on object of type

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a class named FirstViewController which is a subclass of UIViewController and I have a UITableView in the class. I need to transition from this class to a new UIViewController subclass (using segues) when a row is pressed.

I have made the FirstViewController the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource using the code -

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

I am getting an error on this line of code -

```
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

How do I fix this problem since the tableView is found in UITableViewController and not in UIViewController class ?

Edit -

Here's the code related to my table view -

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [sarray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }

    NSString *text = [sarray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = text;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please show how is `tableView` declared in your subclass of your `UIViewController` subclass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply declare tableView as a property:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Comment: Do I need to connect it to anything in the storyboard or only declare it ?

Comment: You'll need to connect tableView to the table view in your storyboard. I've updated my answer to indicate that.

Answer (score 4):

You get a free `UITableView` only if you subclass `UITableViewController`,

```
@interface FirstViewController : UITableViewController
```

Comment: A bit late perhaps but thank you very much. Very useful bit of information.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply declare a table view property on `FirstViewController` using:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

you then need to connect this property to the `Table View` in the story board.