# error with tableview reload data inside connectionDidFinishLoading (parsing by json)

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, ios6

I have a view-controller with tableview with custom tableview cell and after

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{}
```

It gives  this error : **Property 'tableview' not found on object of type 'ViewController2 *'** after using the code below and without it the data is not displayed in the tableview.

```
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

I am unable to figure out how to fix it .Please help me out .I will greatly appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just set your IBOutlet in your nib file for tableview or just check whether the connection which you made already was right

Comment: Thanks for your time,Can you tell me briefly how do I do that? I am using story board.

Comment: sorry for the last comment i wrongly made it for you just connect your tableview iboutlet to your file owner

Comment: Cannot run/build the code as the error exists so cannot try the above suggestion I guess.But I have tableview datasurce,delegate should be connected to viewCOntroller or view ? I dont know >please tell me where to connect the tableview.

Comment: the tableView dataSource and its delegates must be connected to the file owner that is your viewController

Comment: I did that but still get the same error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26598/discussion-between-james-patrick-and-lochana-ragupathy)

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/ try the above sample

Comment: I have done that already: You can suggest something which has navigationCOntroller,json,tableview,didselectrowantindexpath --->viewController instead of alertview or popups so the data passes from one controller to another .Thats the complete requirement I have for now .BUt dd not find any tutorial which has all the above SO I integrated all the above code and I am stuck at this point.

Comment: your question needs a very simple answer look into my answer below  the rest just learn it through by practicing

Comment: I have tried exactly as its suppose to be But I still get the same error.

Comment: can you please post your code for further help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibilities of the above error

```
     1) Your Xib would not have been connected with your ViewController2
     2) You would have not connected your tableView IBOutlet to your xib
     3) In case if you have not @synthesize it if you have declared it as a property
     4) If all the above you did correctly just clean your Xcode and run
```

Comment: Outlets for tableview--- datasource,delegate---is--connected to ViewController2and not class associated with it .In the view COntroller the referencing outlet both datasource,delegate ------is connected---->Table View with custom class referring to ViewController2

Comment: Thanks a ton for your patience and time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255595/tableview-not-found-on-object-of-type  finally try this too and share your results

Comment: Awesome +1 That Worked.I dont know why I need to create an outlet and create a property.I have not seen this anywhere so far. How is it done otherwise ?